# scroll lock still in place after history back

Tags: html

I've implemented a scroll lock toggle when opening an image lightbox, which works fine but remains locked on history back. How could this be resolved?

```
<html>
<body>
    <div class="desktop">
        <img src="docs/docs_overview_desktop.jpg" width="100%" height="auto" usemap="#desktop">
        <map name="desktop">
            <area shape="rect" coords="2057.143,0,2742.857,960" href="#lightbox_000" onclick="ScrollLock()">
        </map>
    </div>
    <div class="lightbox" id="lightbox_000">
        <img src="docs/docs_000.jpg" usemap="#lightbox_000">
        <map name="lightbox_000">
            <area shape="rect" coords="200,200,500,500" href="#_" onclick="ScrollUnlock()">
        </map>
    </div>
    <script>
        function ScrollLock()
        {
            document.getElementsByTagName('*')[0].style.overflow = 'hidden';
        }
        function ScrollUnlock()
        {
            document.getElementsByTagName('*')[0].style.overflow = 'visible';
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: what did you mean by ```history back``` in your question? does it mean pressing the back button of top left of browser?

Comment: @hamid-davodi Yes, in any way or form, on any device!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you add the code `document.getElementsByTagName('*')[0].style.overflow = 'hidden';` to your script `ScrollLock()` function. But that means the element in your HTML (for example the `div` with `class="desktop"`) get the overflow `hidden` and so you **do not** see the scroll in your page. When you click the back button of your browser the page does not reload necessarily. So the overflow is still **hidden**. One way that I think you could use to solve this issue is to force the page to reload after clicking back button. Here I added that code in your script:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>scrol-lock</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="desktop">
        <img src="flower2.png" width="100%" height="auto" usemap="#desktop">
        <map name="desktop">
            <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,500,500" href="#_" onclick="ScrollLock()">
        </map>
    </div>
    <div class="lightbox" id="lightbox_000">
        <img src="flower.jpg" usemap="#flower">
        <map name="flower">
            <area shape="rect" coords="200,200,500,500" href="#_" onclick="ScrollUnlock()">
        </map>
    </div>
    <script>
        function ScrollLock()
        {
            document.getElementsByTagName('*')[0].style.overflow = 'hidden';
        }
        function ScrollUnlock()
        {
            document.getElementsByTagName('*')[0].style.overflow = 'visible';
        }

        document.onmouseover = function() {
            //User's mouse is inside the page.
            window.innerDocClick = true;
            console.log("over");
        }

        document.onmouseleave = function() {
            //User's mouse has left the page.
            console.log("leave");
            window.innerDocClick = false;
        }

        window.onhashchange = function() {
            
            if (window.innerDocClick) {
                window.innerDocClick = false;
            } else {
                if (window.location.hash != '#undefined') {
                    goBack();
                } else {
                    history.pushState("", document.title, window.location.pathname);
                    location.reload();
                }
            }
            
        }
        function goBack() {
            location.reload();
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

In the above code first we detect when the user clicks on **back button** with the help of **window.onhashchange** method and then in the `goback()` function we reload the page that removes the `overflow:hidden`. I changed the `HTML` code to see images in my browser but I think you do not need to change your own HTML file.